Dative of personal pronouns
Hi!                                I am a complete beginner in Latin.
On Duolingo, they have this sentence: Nomen ei est Stephanus.
Aren't we supposed to use sibi here? Why not? (Since Duolingo says nomen mihi and nomen tibi, it seems to me that we are supposed to have nomen sibi instead of nomen ei.)
What's more, why didn't Duolingo say menus nomen? What is the reflexive suus, sua and ssum form about?
Thank you!
Jonas

The difference between sibi and ei in this case is that sibi refers to the subject of the sentence – that would be nomen in this case, so would make no sense – while ei refers to some other person or thing, usually previously mentioned.
Note that mihi and tibi do not have the same property. They just refer to the speaker or the addressee, no matter whether they're the subject or not.
Since the caption of this question is "possessive pronouns," I must mention that these are all not possessive pronouns, but possessive pronouns (and possessive adjectives – they are the same form in Latin) do exist and, lo and behold, exhibit the same phenomenon:

mine/my = meus
thine/thy = tuus
his/her/s = eius (non-subject) / suus (subject)

Grammatically it would be fine to say Nomen eius est Stephanus or Nomen meum est Ionas, it just appears that this is not how Romans typically told their own or someone else's name.
Aulus Gellius (5, 29) wrote:

Duae istae in loquendo figurae notae satis usitataeque sunt: «mihi nomen est Iulius» et «mihi nomen est Iulio»
These two expressions are known and common enough in speech: “mihi nomen est Iulius” and “mihi nomen est Iulio.”

He then goes on to mention a third form he discovered in the Annals of Piso (lost to us), which, however, must have been rare.
So there you have it: You either use the dative or nominative form of the name with the dative of the named person (or a pronoun) + esse.

Thank you very much! However, there are still things that I didn't understand. 1. Both mihi and tibi are dative forms of personal pronouns, is ei one of them as well? Why haven't I seen ei in any declension chart? 2. I didn't really understand the difference between the two expressions of Galius, could you please explain a bit more? 3. At the end, did you mean that I could use dative directly as well? Could you also please give an example?

@JudicaëlLamyrtille ei is the dative of is/ea/id. Why you haven't seen it in a declension chart I do not know, but that's easily fixed: see here. In the expression nomen est, you can use any dative, be it other pronouns (illi, isti) or noun phrases like oratori.

The difference between the expressions mentioned by Gellius is simply that the name is in the nominative in one case, in the dative in the other. The meaning is the same.
